# Kivy - don't draw widget until user selection is made

Tags: python, kivy

I have a dictionary of lists. In my app, the user will select an option from a spinner, which will update the text in the spinner and a bound `StringProperty`, which is used as the key for the dictionary. I am then using `RecycleView` to display and `RecycleGridLayout` to display the list.

I want to start out with the spinner text as 'Select your option'; however, this will throw an error as 'Select your option' is not a dictionary key. Is there a way to only populate the RecycleView after the spinner has been selected? (I realize I could add 'Select your option' as a dictionary key with an empty list; however, these lists pass objects to other widget which also need to be populated - this is a cascading problem!)

Here is some example code:

```
class Overmind(RelativeLayout):
    inventory = ObjectProperty(None, rebind = True)
    current_faction = StringProperty('')

class FactionSelector(BoxLayout):
    faction = StringProperty(None)

class StatViewerApp(App):
    with open('Data\MasterUnitLists\master_inventory.p', 'rb') as file:
        ModelsMaster = load(file)

    def build(self):
        return self.root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    StatViewerApp().run()
```

Kivy lang:

```
Overmind:
    current_faction: faction_selector.faction
    inventory: app.ModelsMaster[root.current_faction]

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_y: 'top'
        anchor_x: 'left'

        FactionSelector:
            id: faction_selector
            size_hint: (0.25,0.2)
            orientation: 'horizontal'

    RecycleView:
        size_hint: (1,0.8)
        viewclass: 'UnitThumbnail'
        data: [{'unit':unit} for unit in root.inventory]
        RecycleGridLayout:
            size_hint: (1,None)
            cols: 5
            spacing: 10
            col_default_width: self.width//5
            height: self.minimum_height

<FactionSelector>:
    faction: facspin.text if facspin.text != 'Select your faction:' else None

    Image:
        size_hint: (0.75,1)
        source: 'Images\\' + root.faction + '\\' + root.faction + '.png' if root.faction else None

    Spinner:
        id: facspin
        text: 'Select your faction:'
        values: (faction for faction in app.ModelsMaster)
```

FactionSelector's spinner updates the StringProperty 'faction', which is bound to the StringProperty 'current_faction', which is used as the key to the 'MasterModels' dictionary. This value is given to 'inventory' ObjectProperty, which is used to populate the RecycleView's data. RecycleView (and UnitThumbnail) are drawn based on data from the inventory - so how can I prevent them from being drawn until a user makes a selection?

Comment: Can you just put a `Label` next to the `Spinner`. The `Label` text would be `Select your option:`, and the `Spinner` text would be a default value?

Comment: @JohnAnderson I don't want a default value - I want the recycleview to stay empty until a selection is made.

Comment: I would consider removing the `data:` designation from the `kv` file. Then extend the  `kivy.uix.spinner.SpinnerOption` class to set the above `data` when released (in addition to the normal `on_release` action).

Comment: @John-Anderson I think I like this idea, and have extended the Spinner class elsewhere to access the _on_dropdown_select method.